# docker swarm create service failed when pull images from private registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm, docker-container, swarm

As a docker beginner, I have built a swarm cluster on 5 Linux server. (docker version 17.12.0-ce)

But when I create a service, I see `docker service ps` command shows `"pulling image failed" error="pull access denied for registry.xxxx.xxx`.

I'm using a private registry which should be use `docker login` at first.

So, how to do the login action when creating a swarm service ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `--with-registry-auth` flag on `docker service create` to pass your credentials.

1. Authenticate if you're not logged in to your private registry
   (`docker login ..`)
2. Create your service:
   `docker service create --with-registry-auth --name my-service my_repo/image:latest`